# What is the best way to save sequence of elements for scrolling forward and backward?

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I'm creating a screen that shows random posts to user. It has two buttons: "back" and "forward". "Forward" button loads next post, "back" button shows the previous post. If list of posts is empty, back button is shadowed (non-clickable). I'm looking for making it using two stacks: one for loaded posts on "forward" button and one for loaded posts on "back" button, so you will scroll through loaded posts while getting to the first post, and vice versa.

Comment: "If list of posts is empty, back button is shadowed" - the term is "disabled", not "shadowed". The term "shadowed" means something else.

Comment: Using two stacks is certainly _one_ possible way to represent history, but given that your history is _traversible_ I think it'd be better to use a general object-graph. Using stacks is too simplistic and prevents you from manipulating history or implementing non-linear history features.

Comment: There isn't any general "best" method, you need to specify what criteria makes the method better than others